# Tracking amount of bytes written to temp tables

Tags: postgresql

With PostgreSQL 9.5, I would like to track the total amount of bytes written (since DB cluster start) to:

1. WAL
2. temp files
3. temp tables

For 1.:

```
select
   pg_size_pretty(archived_count * 16*1024*1024) temp_bytes,
   (now() - stats_reset)::text uptime
from pg_stat_archiver;
```

For 2.:

```
select
   (now() - stats_reset)::text uptime,
   pg_size_pretty(temp_bytes) temp_bytes
from pg_stat_database where datname = 'mydb';
```

**How do I get 3.?**

---

In response to a comment below, I did some tests to check where temp *tables* are actually written.

First, the DB parameter `temp_buffers` is at 8GB on this cluster:

```
select pg_size_pretty(setting::bigint*8192) from pg_settings
     where name = 'temp_buffers';
-- "8192 MB"
```

Lets create a temp table:

```
drop table if exists foo;

create temp table foo as
select random() from generate_series(1, 1000000000);
-- Query returned successfully: 1000000000 rows affected, 10:22 minutes execution time.
```

Check the PostgreSQL backend pid and OID of the created temp table:

```
select pg_backend_pid(), 'pg_temp.foo'::regclass::oid;
-- 46573;398695055
```

Check the RSS size of the backend process

```
~$ grep VmRSS /proc/46573/status
VmRSS:   9246276 kB
```

As can be seen, this is only slightly above the 8GB set with `temp_buffers`.

The data inserted into the temp table is however *immediately* written, and it is written to the normal tablespace directories, *not* temp files:

```
select * from pg_relation_filepath('pg_temp.foo')
-- "base/16416/t3_398695055"
```

Here is the number of files and amount written:

```
with temp_table_files as
(
    select * from pg_ls_dir('base/16416/') fn
        where fn like 't3_398695055%'
)
select
    count(*) as cnt,
    pg_size_pretty(sum((pg_stat_file('base/16416/' || fn)).size)) as size
from temp_table_files;
-- 34;"34 GB"
```

And finally verify that the set of temp *files* owned by this backend PID is indeed empty:

```
with temp_files_per_pid as
(
    with temp_files as
    (
    select
        temp_file,
        (regexp_replace(temp_file, $r$^pgsql_tmp(\d+)\..*$$r$, $rr$\1$rr$, 'g'))::int as pid,
        (pg_stat_file('base/pgsql_tmp/' || temp_file)).size as size
    from pg_ls_dir('base/pgsql_tmp') temp_file
    )
    select pid, pg_size_pretty(sum(size)) from temp_files group by pid order by pid
)
select * from temp_files_per_pid where pid = 46573;
```

Returns nothing.

What is also "interesting", after dropping the temp table

```
DROP TABLE foo;
```

the RSS of the backend process does **not** reduce:

```
~$ grep VmRSS /proc/46573/status
VmRSS:   9254544 kB
```

Doing the following will also not free the RSS again:

```
RESET ALL;
DEALLOCATE ALL;
DISCARD TEMP;
```

Comment: As long as the temp tables _exist_ you can track that in `pg_stat_all_tables`. You could sample the contents of that view to save that for later analysis.

Comment: The info I am after can be retrieved eg like `select * from pg_statio_all_tables where schemaname = 'pg_temp_26'`, but as you mention, that info is only there while the temp table exists (and it isn't aggregated (I don't need it on a per temp table basis)).

Answer (score 1):

What I know, there are not any special metric for temp tables. The temp tables uses session (process) memory to `temp_buffers` size (8MB by default). When these temp buffers are full, then temporary files are generated.

Comment: Mmh, not sure I undestand: Temp tables are not written to temp files (`$PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp/`), but to default tablespace file locations (eg `$PGDATA/base/16416/t27_398692264`) (unless a tablespace is specified when creating the temp table).

Comment: temp tables are written to temp files when temp buffer is full.

Comment: Please see the section I added to the question. `temp_buffers` seems to control the amount of RAM in the backend process for _caching_ the data written to a temp table - but the data is immediately written to disk, and it is written to default tablespace files, not temp files.

Comment: Has sense - I was wrong. The sense of temp_buffers is skip wall logging and checkpointing.

Comment: My understanding: it is not about WAL/checkpointing, because that doesn't apply to temp tables. It's about caching blocks in backend process specific temp buffers instead of caching in shared buffers. The latter wouldn't make sense, as the temp table is local (there isn't anything like global temp table in PostgreSQL). Anyway, we've now turned to a completely different topic/discussion;)

Comment: yes, I wrote "skip wall log". More - some operation on local buffers can be little bit faster., because you don't need wait for locks for access to shared memory.